Many to Many Relationship in Supabase for Swift
How can I select all expenses and also their tags. I have expense table and tags table and then the expenses_tags table.
In Swift I have the following:
struct Expense: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int?
    let name: String
    let amount: Double 
    let budgetId: Int
    var receiptPath: String?
    var tags: [Tag] = [] 
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case amount = "amount"
        case budgetId = "budget_id"
        case receiptPath = "receipt_path"
    }
}


struct Tag: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String
}

Currently, when I fetch expenses I use the following command.
let expenses: [Expense] = try await supabaseClient
                    .from("expenses")
                    .select()
                    .eq("budget_id", value: budgetId)
                    .execute()
                    .value

I tried the following:
 let expenses: [Expense] = try await supabaseClient
                    .from("expenses")
                    .select("id, name, amount, budget_id, receipt_path, tags(id, name)")
                    .eq("budget_id", value: budgetId)
                    .execute()
                    .value

But it keeps throwing exceptions.
